# Code wars: Why does this function work against whitespace and numbers?

Tags: javascript, string

I need to check if two strings are in the same case. I have my own solution to this problem but I found this version and I can't understand how/why it works:

```
function sameCase(a, b){
 if(a.toUpperCase() === a.toLowerCase() || b.toLowerCase() === b.toUpperCase()){
    return -1
  }else if(a === a.toLowerCase() && b === b.toLowerCase() || a === a.toUpperCase() && b === b.toUpperCase()){
      return 1
  }else{
    return 0
  }
}
```

Specifically this `if` statement:

```
if(a.toUpperCase() === a.toLowerCase() || b.toLowerCase() === b.toUpperCase()){ return -1}
```

I know this check works against numeric characters and white space, but I don't understand why this works since it doesn't look to take these items into account.

my question: why does this function work against non-letters and numbers and even white space?

Comment: The *only* characters which change from the output of `toUpperCase` to the output of `toLowerCase` are letters. So this is testing if both strings contain only non-letter (i.e. whitespace, numbers and symbols) characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The non-letters are not modified by `toUpperCase` or `toLowerCase`. Try picturing a lowercase `9` or  . That's because all those functions do is replace the individual letter characters with their uppercase or lowercase equivalents.

So, that code segment just basically checks if the string is entirely composed of non-letter characters (because `924 "` is the same in both uppercase or lowercase, however `a123` is not the same in both uppercase and lowercase and thus will fail that `if` statement).